# Why can't I clone a repo into /usr/local?

Tags: git, github, proxy, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to clone a github repository to /usr/local and I get the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gsjaardema/seacas.git/': 
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

I am behind a firewall and have set my proxy in my `.gitconfig`. I **can** clone this repo to any directory under `/Users/$USER` but **cannot** clone it to anything under /opt or /usr/local.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.4 and am using git version 2.8.2. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have write access to /isr/local?  (error looks unrelated to the issue you mentioned?)

Comment: Please do not pollute /opt  or /usr/local with git repos.  You can checkout the code some where else.. You may install binaries to /opt/ or /usr/local if needed. (typically provided by a make install step)

Comment: @Jayan I do have write access to /usr/local and own that directory. Thank you for the suggestion about cloning somewhere else and then building the code under /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to another protocol or to use this configuration :

```
git config --global url."http://".insteadOf https://
```

This should add teh following entry to your config file:

```
[url "git://"]   
    insteadOf = https://
```

But now you will need to have ssh key.

Comment: Did you mean to add `ssh://` ? The git protocol has nothing to do with ssh, AIUI.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. It is made up of two parts:

1 - I fixed the permission to `/usr/local` by running (source: http://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/)

`sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

2 - I cloned the repo without `sudo`.

I haven't tried these steps individually but I believe it was the combination of the two. Hopefully my answer is helpful to others.

Though upon further inspection, I like the idea suggested by @Jayan. Clone the repo somewhere else and build it in `/usr/local`. That said, to do this, I'd still need to repair permission (step #1).

Answer (score 0):

The `/usr` folder is owned by root.

You can clone into `/usr/local` or the more commonly used `/usr/src` by using the `sudo` command.

```
cd /usr/local
sudo git clone {repo}
```

Usually, `/usr/local` is for your own local projects. If I were later putting one of those projects onto GitHub or sharing it for download on a website I would first move it to `/usr/src`.